# Multiple Systems inside assemblies

Tags: c#, .net

When I look at assemblies in my *references* I can see multiple ***System*** namespaces:

[image]

So which one of them do I call when I have this code in my .cs file?

```
using System;   // <---------
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

How does this ***using*** algorithm finds appropriate namespace in these assemblies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespaces effectively merge across all referenced assemblies.  When you have `using System;`, you're importing types from the whole namespace, meaning that all types in that namespace in all referenced assemblies are made available.

A namespace doesn't even exist until there's a type in it.

If you wanted, you could define your own types in the `System` namespace, which makes them available whenever you have `using System;`.  That's not to say that you *should*, only that it's possible.

Comment: Ok. But it means that there could be a name coflicts if someone theoretically will create some methods that are already created inside a System namespace, right?

Comment: That's true. C# provides a mechanism for resolving those conflicts: [extern alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias).

Answer (score 2):

Namespaces exist to package related types (classes, enums, ...) logically and to reduce the risk of name ambiguity.
You can reference a couple assemblies that have a same namespace to your project.

Imagine you have referenced two assemblies and they both contain "namepsace2":

```
assembly1
    namespace1
    namespace2
            class1
            class2

assembly2
    namespace2
            class2
            class3
    namespace3
    namepsace4
```

When you use

```
using namepsace2;
```

you can access all types that reside inside "namespace2" in both assemblies without fully gualifiying their names:

```
    // you can use  
    class1 c1 = new class1();
    // instead of
    namepsace2.class1 c1 = new namepsace2.class1();

    // And also class3 can be used similarly
```

But "class2" causes broblem. You have to use its fully qualified name to tell the compiler excatly which "class2" you are interested in.